# Calling a .NET Messagebox from Powerbuilder 12.6.NET

Tags: wpf, powerbuilder

I'm trying to wrap my head around calling .NET functions from within a WPF PowerBuilder 12.6 app. Searching the docs doesn't tell me exactly where I should be going, but I'm probably not looking in the right place. In the "Using Multithreading" section of "PowerBuilder .NET Features", there's the following code (edited for relevance):

```
//Declare a .NET Class
System.Threading.Thread ithread

ithread = create
ithread.IsBackground = true
```

When I put that code into a script window, Intellisense kicks in and shows me the IsBackground method. However, if I try the following:

```
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox lo_MB

lo_MB = create System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox
lo_MB.
```

I get nothing but the standard object properties. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with PowerBuilder but for .Net I use C# or Vulcan (yes, that exists and it's quite nice too). I use System.Windows.MessageBox in WPF programs. System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox is for Forms based programs and that's why it doesn't give you properties.